# Discord bot problem. discord.py AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'channel'

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm sorry that I post again today, but I'm just starting to create bots and there are many problems that I don't understand even though I dig the whole internet.

I have created a table in embed that is to be uploaded to the feed every hour, but there are bugs.

My problem:
`AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'channel'`

Here is my code:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    crypto_hour.start()
    print('Bot is active!')

@tasks.loop(hours=10)
async def crypto_hour():
    channel = bot.get_channel(809155804170682408)
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title = ":D",
        color = discord.Color.blue(),
    )
    url = 'http://api.coinlayer.com/live?access_key='
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        raw_response = await session.get(url)
        response = await raw_response.text()
        response = json.loads(response)
        embed.set_author(name=':D')
        embed.add_field(name='• **Bitcoin (BTC)**:', value=str(f"{response['rates']['BTC']}PLN"), inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name='• **Ethereum (ETH)**:', value=str(f"{response['rates']['ETH']}PLN"), inline=True)
        await bot.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `send()` on `channel` which you have already defined earlier and not on `bot.channel`. Therefore you should edit you last line to be:

```py
await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Comment: That means that no channel was found with that id using `channel = bot.get_channel(809155804170682408)`

Comment: But this channel exists, I copy its ID and paste it.

Comment: Make sure the channel exists. Also, try `channel = await bot.get_channel(809155804170682408)`

Comment: I've already solved the problem, instead of bot.get.channel I used client.get.channel and replaced the function executing the command with channel.send. Could it be so?

Comment: Since bot is an implementation of client that works too but it will make little difference.